# GNU assembler errors on intel syntax code that used to work in 2007

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I'm finally getting back to my colorforth project, which I gave up on years ago when an update to binutils broke all my sources. here's an example of what's happening:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ cat /tmp/test.as
    .intel_syntax
    .arch i386
    .code32
    mov eax,[foo + eax*4]
    lea    ecx,[ecx*4+0x9e0]
    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [edi*4-0x4]
    jmp    DWORD PTR [ecx*4+0x12cc]
    lea    edx,[ecx+edx*1]
```

the first non-directive line is from examples from the manual: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html#i386_002dMemory, and the rest are from an objdump disassembly with `--disassembler-options=intel`. every single one fails to assemble:

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ as /tmp/test.as
/tmp/test.as: Assembler messages:
/tmp/test.as:4: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
/tmp/test.as:5: Error: too many memory references for `lea'
/tmp/test.as:6: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
/tmp/test.as:8: Error: too many memory references for `lea'
/tmp/test.as:7: Error: invalid operands (*UND* and *ABS* sections) for `*'
```

I've been googling all evening with no luck. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but damned if I can figure out what it is. I've `apt-get source binutils`, but don't know where to start looking.

```
jcomeau@aspire:~$ as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.25.90.20151209
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `i686-linux-gnu'.
```

so what's the magic incantation to get cooking with `gas` again?

Comment: Try `.intel_syntax noprefix` . If you don't use `noprefix` GAS will still want register names to be prefixed with a `%` (percent sign) which looks to be the cause of your issues.

Comment: oh man. so simple. please put that in as an answer and I'll accept it. and THANK YOU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using GNU Assembler with the `.intel_syntax` directive you'll want to use the `noprefix` option to force *AS* to not require a `%` (percent sign) to be prepended to register names (like AT&T syntax). You should probably use:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
```